# Extracting submatches using boost regex in c++

Tags: c++, regex, boost

I'm trying to extract submatches from a text file using boost regex.  Currently I'm only returning the first valid line and the full line instead of the valid email address.  I tried using the iterator and using submatches but I wasn't having success with it.  Here is the current code:

```
if(Myfile.is_open()) {
    boost::regex pattern("^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,4})$");
    while(getline(Myfile, line)) {
            string::const_iterator start = line.begin();
            string::const_iterator end = line.end();
            boost::sregex_token_iterator i(start, end, pattern);
            boost::sregex_token_iterator j;
            while ( i != j) {
            cout << *i++ << endl;  

    } 
    Myfile.close(); 
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use [boost::smatch](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/ref/match_results.html).

```
boost::regex pattern("what(ever) ...");
boost::smatch result;
if (boost::regex_search(s, result, pattern)) {
    string submatch(result[1].first, result[1].second);
    // Do whatever ...
}
```

Comment: Perhaps my Regex is wrong but that's not yielding proper results for me.

Answer (score 17):

```
const string pattern = "(abc)(def)";  
const string target = "abcdef"; 

boost::regex regexPattern(pattern, boost::regex::extended); 
boost::smatch what; 

bool isMatchFound = boost::regex_match(target, what, regexPattern); 
if (isMatchFound) 
{ 
    for (unsigned int i=0; i < what.size(); i++) 
    { 
        cout << "WHAT " << i << " " << what[i] << endl; 
    } 
}
```

The output is the following

```
WHAT 0 abcdef 
WHAT 1 abc 
WHAT 2 def
```

Boost uses parenthesized submatches, and the first submatch is always the full matched string. regex_match has to match the entire line of input against the pattern, if you are trying to match a substring, use regex_search instead.

The example I used above uses the posix extended regex syntax, which is specified using the boost::regex::extended parameter. Omitting that parameter changes the syntax to use perl style regex syntax. Other regex syntax is available.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
string submatch(result[1].first, result[1].second);
```

causes errors in visual c++ (I tested against 2012, but expect earlier version do, too)

See https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/cpp-netlib/0Szv2WcgAtc for analysis.

Answer (score 0):

The most simplest way to convert `boost::sub_match` to `std::string` :

```cpp
boost::smatch result;
// regex_search or regex_match ...
string s = result[1];
```